# hsqldb update on insert

Tags: jdbc, insert, hsqldb

Does anyone know of a solution to make HSQLDB update columns by calling INSERT.  I would like my code to be able to insert, and if there's already data, to update that data.  I know MySQl, I believe, has 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'.  I can't seem to find any recent documentation on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good sample is sometimes better [the formal documentation on MERGE statement](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_merge_statement) :)

**Sample 1**

For a table (`MY_TABLE`) with tho columns (`COL_A` and `COL_B`), where the first column is a primary key:

```
MERGE INTO MY_TABLE AS t USING (VALUES(?,?)) AS vals(a,b) 
        ON t.COL_A=vals.a
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.COL_B=vals.b
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES vals.a, vals.b
```

**Sample 2**

Let's add another column (`COL_C`) to our table:

```
MERGE INTO MY_TABLE AS t USING (VALUES(?,?,?)) AS vals(a,b,c) 
        ON t.COL_A=vals.a
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.COL_B=vals.b, t.COL_C=vals.c
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES vals.a, vals.b, vals.c
```

**Sample 3**

Now let's change the primary key to consist of first two columns (`COL_A` and `COL_B`):

```
MERGE INTO MY_TABLE AS t USING (VALUES(?,?,?)) AS vals(a,b,c) 
        ON t.COL_A=vals.a AND t.COL_B=vals.b
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.COL_C=vals.c
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES vals.a, vals.b, vals.c
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

HSQLDB provides the MERGE statement for this purpose.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_merge_statement

Alternatively, you can write a short stored procedure to insert, then catch any constraint violation exception and perform an update.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_psm_handlers

Update: From version 2.3.4 HSQLDB also supports the MySQL syntax for ON DUPLICATE KEY